# Rails with Devise Only allow school emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, devise

I have an application running Ruby on Rails with Devise for the user management. However, when a user edits their account or a new user signs up I only want them to be allowed to use my school's email address, so it must contain @uwo.ca

However I would like to find a solution that will allow for me to add more emails in the future..

I found this code online but I'm unsure where to put it

```
INVALID_EMAILS = %w(uwo.ca)
validates_format_of :email, :without => /#{INVALID_EMAILS.map{|a| Regexp.quote(a)}.join('|')}/, :message => "That's a BAD EMAIL."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think imprementing custom validation is better way.

How about this?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  VALID_EMAILS = %w(uwo\.ca, example\.com)
  validate :validate_email_formats

  def validate_email_formats
    VALID_EMAILS.each do |email_format|
      return if self.email.to_s =~ /.+@#{email_format}$/
    end
    errors.add(:email, "is a BAD EMAIL.")
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tested this? There is at least one, maybe two problems that I see.

Comment: I tried this and it works, what are the errors you see? @Jordan

Comment: Sorry, I modified a part of code. It had errors when I posted first time.
`%w(uwo.ca, example.com)`  => `%w(uwo\.ca, example\.com)`

Comment: Arrays created with the `%w` sigil are split on whitespace, so the comma in `%w(uwo.ca, example.com)` means the first array element will be `"uwo.ca,"` with a trailing comma. And why not use `RegExp.union` instead of a loop?

Answer (score 4):

This is a validation. It goes in your model. There's an entire Rails Guide about validations: [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). Read it before you write any more code.

The code you posted was apparently intended for blacklisting multiple email domains (ergo `INVALID_EMAILS`), which makes it ill-suited for your purpose, which is whitelisting a single domain. It also wasn't very good code to begin with. All you want to do is validate that the email address ends with `@uwo.ca`, which means you want it to match the regular expression `/@uwo\.ca$/`. For that, the validation would look like this:

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /@uwo\.ca$/,
  :message => "That's a bad email."
```

Also, consider using [I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) for your error messages instead of hard-coding them in your model.